# infinite loop when watching parent object, watcher does not update any value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that generates a C3js chart. I have an object that contains various C3 properties. If the incoming element already has a `chartOptions` object, it is used, however if not, then the default object is added.

```
scope.elementObject.chartOptions = scope.elementObject.chartOptions || chartOptions;
```

I'm attempting to watch for any changes on the `chartOptions` object because it will be interacted with outside the directive, however simply creating a watcher without adding any functionality causes an infinite loop. None of the regular infinite loop solutions seem to work, because I'm not seemingly modifying the object inside the watcher.

```
scope.$watch('elementObject.chartOptions', function () {
    console.log('changed')
}, true);
//INFINITE LOOP
```

If, however, I watch a child object, then I do not get an infinite loop, such as

```
scope.$watch('elementObject.chartOptions.data', function () {
    console.log('changed')
}, true);
//NO INFINITE LOOP
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('newchart', function () {

    return {
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            elementObject: "=element"
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };
    function link(scope, elem) {

        var el = elem[0];
        var chartOptions = {
            data: {
                columns: [['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]],
                type: 'spline',
                labels: false
            },
            interaction: { enabled: true },
            grid: { x: { show: false }, y: { show: false } },
            legend: { show: true, position: 'bottom' },
            tooltip: { show: true, grouped: true }
        };

        scope.elementObject.chartOptions = scope.elementObject.chartOptions || chartOptions;
        scope.elementObject.chartOptions.bindto = el;

        var chart = c3.generate(scope.elementObject.chartOptions);

        scope.$watch('elementObject.chartOptions', function () {
            console.log('changed')
        }, true);        
    };
});
```

I need to be able to watch for changes on any of the properties of the `chartOptions` object, not just to data, as was the example above.

Comment: Why not use this angularjs directive http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/

Comment: I've seen that before, but it didn't quite seem to fit my needs. I'm building a dashboard on top of gridster with a lot of moving parts, and it ended up being easier to create my own directive, until this problem popped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the issue was caused by this line:

```
scope.elementObject.chartOptions.bindto = el;
```

the `element` object argument in the link function is a jquery wrapper of the DOM element being manipulated. Placing a watcher on that specifically, caused the infinite loop.

Because I was including the `bindto` property in the options object, the whole object was then returning the infinite loop when watched.

From the C3js documentation about `bindto`:

> If this option is not specified, the chart will be generated but not be set. Instead, we can access the element by chart.element and set it by ourselves

So the solution is to not include a `bindto` property in the options object, and then add the generated svg into the directive by accessing it through `chart.element`, such as:

```
function link(scope, elem) {

    ...

    var chart = c3.generate(scope.elementObject.chartOptions);
    elem.html(chart.element)
}
```